# Swift 3 - .addTarget() method not triggering Selector

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to create dynamic radio buttons based on Firebase data. I am hoping to arrange the buttons in a vertical stack, and essentially when they are clicked I would hope for them to disappear and display another view:

```
class PollController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var passLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pollImage: UIImageView!
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var pollRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

var pass = ""
var passedImageURL = ""

var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

var buttons = [UIButton]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    pollRef = ref.child("Polls").child(pass)
    passLabel.text = pass
    pollImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: passedImageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "test"))


    pollRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    let numberOfChildren = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "answers").childrenCount
    self.passLabel.text = String(numberOfChildren)
    print(numberOfChildren)

    var stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: self.buttons)

        // create button1
    for x in 0..<numberOfChildren {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.posX, y: self.posY, width: 60, height: 20))
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
            button.setTitle("No", for: .normal)
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, for: .normal)
            // if the selected button cannot be reclick again, you can use .Disabled state
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkboxredtick.png")!, for: .selected)
            button.tag = Int(x)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            stackView.addSubview(button)
            self.buttons.append(button)
            // create other buttons and add into buttons ...
        }
        })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!){
    for button in buttons {
        button.isSelected = false
    }
    sender.isSelected = true
    // you may need to know which button to trigger some action
    // let buttonIndex = buttons.indexOf(sender)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **SWIFT 3.0** or later,

Then you must define add target method like below as _: is missing in the **selector** parameter.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:)), for: .TouchUpInside)
```

Also check id you have declares **myStackview** variable here. if you declared then try to add it as :

```
 self.myStackview
```

Comment: halfway there, still having issues with #selector and the method; new to swift/iOS and don't fully understand the concept

Comment: ohh..seems like you have declared your **buttonAction** function inside your curly braces. Please move function to outside of that code. I mean in the same hierarchy where you find **didReceiveMemoryWarning** method.

Comment: I would then need to move the button array as well?

Comment: you can declare your button array variable  as class variable so that you can access it anywhere in the class

Comment: got it, then it is telling me that I have no initializer

Comment: declare it as like.

let buttonArray = [UIButton]() 

and everytime you add button in it . add it like :


buttonArray.append(button1)

Comment: use self to access method       #selector(self.buttonAction(_:))

Comment: Really appreciate the help. it is saying my class has no member 'buttonAction.' Unsure why as I have moved the method to the class level

Comment: did you check with self keyword?

Comment: I did. Closed it up I will paste code tomorrow really appreciate help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143236/discussion-between-balaji-galave-and-tccpg288).

Answer (score 1):

Your button declaration is `func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!)`. Note that there are no underscore before `sender`. This means that you need to specify the name of the argument when you call the function. Replace the underscore in the selector with the argument name `sender`

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

You can also add an underscore in front of the argument name in the function.

```
func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton!)
```

Also, I noticed that the code is in Swift 3 seeing most of the syntax. So, the control event for touch up inside in Swift 3 is `touchUpInside` and not `TouchUpInside`

Comment: Much appreciated, new to Swift and it sounds like a lot of changes were incorporated in Swift 3, particularly related to syntax